# Flutter: when to use `print` and `debugPrint`?

Tags: flutter

There is some confusion when to use `print` and `debugPrint`, so there are some statements which may be false, and which should be clearified:

1. When using the direct `print` method then it will bring a lot of a trash into production, will not it?
2. When using the `debugPrint` method then it will print only while developing, or it will print also in production?
3. When I generate a release file (apk), will not it delete all the `print` calls to optimize the app and reduce the release file size?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1. and 3. If you use the command `flutter logs` you will see the output of the print function in all applications you have installed in the phone/emulator. This means that even if the app is in release mode, it will still be printed in the terminal.
2. `debugPrint` generally is used to avoid the printing limit of each OS, if  default `debugPrintThrottled` callback is used. It will also print in production, but you can customize it to work only in dev mode:

```
import "package:flutter/foundation.dart"; //allows to use kReleaseMode

void main() {

    if (kReleaseMode) {
      debugPrint = (String? message, {int? wrapWidth}) {};
    }
}
```

With this when the `debugPrint` statements in your code called in production, it won’t be printed to the console since you gave this function an empty callback.

Comment: The example above for overriding debugPrint in release mode is a good solution. Another way to do it with slightly less code is to import flutter/foundation.dart and check kReleaseMode. For example: ```if (kReleaseMode) { debugPrint = (String? message, { int? wrapWidth }) {}; }```

Answer (score 1):

1. When using the direct print method then it will bring a lot of a trash into production, will not it?

*both print & debugPrint cause unnecessary resource consumption as in production mode.*

2. When using the debugPrint method then it will print only while developing, or it will print also in production?

*both print & debugPrint print in production mode.*

3. When I generate a release file (apk), will not it delete all the print calls to optimize the app and reduce the release file size?

*No, nothing will be deleted.
However, you can optimise your code as follows*

*01. avoid print statements in production code, use debugPrint instead*

*02. Use debugPrint with kDebugMode*

```
    void f(int x) {
     if (kDebugMode) {
        print('debug: $x');
     }
     ...
    }
```

*the main differnece between print & debugPrint is,*

*print() -  this will omit printing after certain length & print accepts anything, not just string*

*debugPrint - accepts only strings & omit can be avoided using wrapWidth property*

[read here](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/avoid_print)